# SWIFT: How to randomly select 1 of 5 obstacles and run an action on it, and repeat this process every second?

Tags: swift, random, sprite-kit

I am trying to create a game where there are five different obstacles, one of which is selected at random every second, and moves from the top of the screen to the bottom of the screen. This should create an obstacle field for the player to navigate. I am able to have the first obstacle move down the screen, but instead of another coming down the screen a second later, I keep getting Thread 1: signal SIGABRT errors, despite trying to fix the problem.

Here is my code:

```
func randomize() {
    smallMiddleObstacle.size = CGSizeMake(self.frame.width - 180, obstacleHeight)
    smallMiddleObstacle.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.width / 2, self.frame.height + smallMiddleObstacle.frame.height / 4)
    smallMiddleObstacle.color = UIColor.blueColor()

    bigMiddleObstacle.size = CGSizeMake(self.frame.width - 100, obstacleHeight)
    bigMiddleObstacle.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.width / 2, self.frame.height + bigMiddleObstacle.frame.height / 4)
    bigMiddleObstacle.color = UIColor.blueColor()

    rightObstacle.size = CGSizeMake(self.frame.width * 1.4, obstacleHeight)
    rightObstacle.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.width, self.frame.height + rightObstacle.frame.height / 4)
    rightObstacle.color = UIColor.blueColor()

    leftObstacle.size = CGSizeMake(self.frame.width * 1.4, obstacleHeight)
    leftObstacle.position = CGPointMake(0, self.frame.height + leftObstacle.frame.height / 4)
    leftObstacle.color = UIColor.blueColor()

    rightObstacleInPair.size = CGSizeMake(self.frame.width * 0.7, obstacleHeight)
    rightObstacleInPair.position.x = self.frame.width
    rightObstacleInPair.color = UIColor.blueColor()

    obstaclePair.addChild(rightObstacleInPair)

    leftObstacleInPair.size = CGSizeMake(self.frame.width * 0.7, obstacleHeight)
    leftObstacleInPair.position.x = 0
    leftObstacleInPair.color = UIColor.blueColor()

    obstaclePair.addChild(leftObstacleInPair)

    obstaclePair.position.y = self.frame.height + obstaclePair.frame.height / 4

    let distance = CGFloat(self.frame.height + obstacleHeight)
    let move = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -distance, duration: NSTimeInterval(0.005 * distance))
    let remove = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    moveAndRemove = SKAction.sequence([move, remove])

    let random = Int(arc4random_uniform(4))

    if random == 0 {
        addChild(smallMiddleObstacle)
        smallMiddleObstacle.runAction(moveAndRemove)
    } else if random == 1 {
        addChild(bigMiddleObstacle)
        bigMiddleObstacle.runAction(moveAndRemove)
    } else if random == 2 {
        addChild(rightObstacle)
        rightObstacle.runAction(moveAndRemove)
    } else if random == 3 {
        addChild(leftObstacle)
        leftObstacle.runAction(moveAndRemove)
    } else {
        addChild(obstaclePair)
        obstaclePair.runAction(moveAndRemove)
    }

}



override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    if !isGameStarted {

        isGameStarted = true


        let spawn = SKAction.runBlock({
        () in

            self.randomize()

    })

        let delay = SKAction.waitForDuration(1.5)
        let spawnDelay = SKAction.sequence([spawn, delay])
        let spawnDelayForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(spawnDelay)

        self.runAction(spawnDelayForever)



    }



}
```

Thanks

Comment: As you step through the code, what line faults?

Comment: I can start the simulator fine but after 1.5 seconds roughly, the simulator crashes and gives me this message in the debugger: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent: <SKSpriteNode> name:'(null)' texture:['nil'] position:{414, 0} scale:{1.00, 1.00} size:{289.79998779296875, 50} anchor:{0.5, 0.5} rotation:0.00'

Comment: Can you identify the line of code that creates the fault?

Comment: Yeah I am pretty sure that it is breaking the second time that "spawn" is being called. So if I change the last line from "self.runAction(spawnDelayForever)" to "self.runAction(spawnDelay)" it works fine, but only once. Sorry if I am not explaining this clearly, I'm bad at explaining things.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to `removeFromParent` the already `addChild`'s so, the second time you call `randomize`method your have an "Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent:"

First of all give a `name` to your nodes if you have not already done.

Everytime **before** you make an `addChild`, you must be sure you don't already have added it, to know you can do:

For example:

```
if let child = self.childNodeWithName(smallMiddleObstacle.name) {
     child.removeFromParent()
}
```